# Issue with Aggregated Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to SUM up a Group of CELLS by their Dates in Access...so that a report will give 1 of each date....and the TOTAL amount of CELLS that have that date.  Followed by the next...

I'm sure it's a combination of things. or something simple but could someone please explain how I would do this?

Thanks

EVV Table

```
+-------------+--------+
| DateInputed | Claims |  
+-------------+--------+  
|02/08/2021   | 15     |  
|02/08/2021   | 31     |  
|03/01/2020   | 21     | 
+-------------+--------+
```

Report Should look like

```
By Date Report
-------------
02/08/2021             46

03/01/2020             21

--------------
Totals                 67
```

With Distinct obviously being used by the Date portion Query and A SUM being done per Date.... Does this make more sense

Here's what I've thought of trying
[image: Image of Explanation of Report Display]

Comment: What did you try? Are you trying an aggregate query? Edit question to show attempted SQL. Also show sample data and desired output as text tables. Or are you trying report Sorting & Grouping with aggregate calcs?

Comment: @June7 I've added a bit more information so that you can advise HOW to go about...i've tried Aggrogated...but I'm not finding the write SQL for that...maybe it can't be done and needs to be done via multiple Queries? or there could be an esiser way? Please help

Comment: Didn't provide attempted SQL. Have you even looked at report Sorting & Grouping with aggregate calcs? Report allows display of detail data as well as summary calcs.

Comment: Ok...so when i attempted to Group I grouped obviously by Date...but then ALL the Claims Show...I don't want that...I only want a SUM of the claims in that group, to display. Is that doable?

Comment: Or i could try now Group By as a SQL....

Comment: Need to show attempted SQL. Or in report set Detail section not visible so only group/report header/footer show.

Answer (score 0):

Sooo I was Massively over thinking this...and would like to credit @June7 With the win since they were able to point out Grouping and Sorting to me.....GROUPING

So Here's my Answer that worked

I Created a SQL Query

```
SELECT EVV.DateInputed, Sum(EVV.ClaimNumber) AS Total_Claim, Sum(EVV.[Total Failed Claims]) AS Total_Fail FROM EVV GROUP BY EVV.DateInputed HAVING (((EVV.DateInputed)>= Forms]![Search for EVV Totals]![fromDate] And (EVV.DateInputed)<=[Forms]![Search for EVV Totals]![toDate]));
```

Then I created a Simple Report based on that and BAMB Instant Answer.  So thank you for those of everyone that was helping